# How can we map a string with case sensitive?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have my code like,

```
string firstLineOfRecord = "front images,Currency Code,Date,BackImages,Domination";
string[] fieldArrayRecord = firstLineOfRecord.Split(',');

string fields = "FrontImages,BackImages,Domination,CurrencyCode,SerialNumber";
string[] fieldArrayList = fields.Split(',');
List<int> mappedList = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i< fieldArrayList.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < fieldArrayRecord.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (fieldArrayList[i] == fieldArrayRecord[j])
        {
            mappedList.Add(j);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i map, the "front Images" with "FrontImages".

As iam the beginner i dont know how to solve this.Kindly tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: No.The "firstLineOfRecord" is from server. it can hold any value. what should i do in that case?

Comment: The mapped List should contain the indizes of all matches found?

Comment: You should explain the problem in more detail. It looks like you are trying to compare the text of elements in the first array to find the index in the second is this correct?

Comment: @ Florian Schmidinger: yes.

Comment: @ Sayse: yes you are correct

Comment: Think you rather need a pair of indizes to map correctly one for input and one for destination... Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, your problems are spaces and case sensitivity
so you can use

```
fieldArrayList[i].Replace(" ","").ToLower() == 
    fieldArrayRecord[j].Replace(" ","").ToLower()
```

Comment: [Never use `ToLower` to compare strings!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660232/993547)

Comment: You are right, I agree to your comment. But he asked for just one equation so I gave this answer to be simple. If he asked for more generic solution, I'd never gave that.

Comment: A simple `string.Equals` would be fine.

Comment: @KavithaP.: Why what?

Comment: @KavithaP.: See the link in the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

For such a fuzzy match, you first need to identify the valid identifiers to ignore (in this case a space).

You could do something like this: You strip out all those identifiers. Then compare case and culture insensitive.

```
string normalizedHeaderString = "FrontImages";
string normalizedInputString = "front images";

foreach (string c in new[] { " " }) /* the strings to strip out */
{
    normalizedHeaderString = normalizedHeaderString.Replace(c, null);
    normalizedInputString = normalizedInputString.Replace(c, null);
}

if (string.Equals( normalizedHeaderString
                 , normalizedInputString
                 , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
                 )
   )
{ /* do your logic, like saving the index, etc */ }
```

This is a little hacky, but you get the idea. You'd better use a custom implementation of a `StringComparer` that just ignores the characters to strip out.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstLineOfRecord = "front images,Currency Code,Date,BackImages,Domination";
        string[] fieldArrayRecord = firstLineOfRecord.Split(',');

        string fields = "FrontImages,BackImages,Domination,CurrencyCode,SerialNumber";
        string[] fieldArrayList = fields.Split(',');
        List<int> mappedList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldArrayRecord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fieldArrayList.Any(s => string.Equals( fieldArrayRecord[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty), s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                mappedList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        foreach (int index in mappedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
3
4
```

Or using a dictionary:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstLineOfRecord = "front images,Currency Code,Date,BackImages,Domination";

        string fields = "FrontImages,BackImages,Domination,CurrencyCode,SerialNumber";

        var dataFields = firstLineOfRecord.Split(',').Select((x, index) => new { FieldName = x.Replace(" ", string.Empty), Index = index });
        var tableFields = fields.Split(',').Select((x, index) => new { FieldName = x, Index = index });

        Dictionary<int, int> mapping = (from dataField in dataFields
                                        let tableField = tableFields.SingleOrDefault(x => string.Equals(dataField.FieldName, x.FieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                        where tableField != null
                                        select new { DF = dataField.Index, TF = tableField.Index })
                                       .ToDictionary(c => c.DF, c => c.TF);

        // Test:

        string[] dataFieldsArray = firstLineOfRecord.Split(',');
        string[] tableFieldsArray = fields.Split(',');

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int,int> pair in mapping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "TableField '{0}' Index {1} has to be mapped to DataField '{2}' Index {3}",
                tableFieldsArray[pair.Value], pair.Value, dataFieldsArray[pair.Key],pair.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TableField 'FrontImages' Index 0 has to be mapped to DataField 'front images' Index 0
TableField 'CurrencyCode' Index 3 has to be mapped to DataField 'Currency Code' Index 1
TableField 'BackImages' Index 1 has to be mapped to DataField 'BackImages' Index 3
TableField 'Domination' Index 2 has to be mapped to DataField 'Domination' Index 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it with a LINQ query:

```
string firstLineOfRecord = "front images,Currency Code,Date,BackImages,Domination";

string[] fieldArrayRecord = firstLineOfRecord.Split(',')
                                             .Select(x => x.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
                                             .ToArray();
// Test it, prints True.
fieldArrayRecord.Contains("FrontImages", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Note this will replace *any* white space between those letters and will alter the given `fieldArrayRecord`.