# slicker way of writing IF statement

Tags: c#

can you please advise me on a slicker way of saying:

```
if (PK.ToString() == "id" || "Id" || "ID" || "iD"))
{

}
```

as this throws a || operator cant be applied to instances of bool and string

```
finished asking the question but cant post because Q does not meet requirements please ignore this attempt to fill white space
```

Comment: use `switch` statement

Comment: @Ramanlfc Why?  This is clearly a case insensitive comparison that the OP wants.

Comment: Use String.toUpper - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Servy this is not a dup of that.

Comment: `if (PK.ToString().Equals("id",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`string.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that lets you specify that you want case insensitive comparison

```
if(string.Compare(PK.ToString(), "ID", true) == 0)
```

Other options include converting to upper or lower case

```
if(PK.ToString().ToLower() == "id")
```

and

```
if(PK.ToString().ToUpper() == "id")
```

But you need to be aware of the culture because translating to upper or lower case doesn't always have the expected results depending on the culture.  In which case you might find it better to use ordinal or the invariant culture.

```
if(PK.ToString().Equals("ID", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

or

```
if(PK.ToString().Equals("ID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: this is flagging condition must be of type bool

Comment: @John Yeah, forgot to compare it to 0.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to lowercase:

```
PK.ToString().toLowerCase().Equals("id")
```

Comment: [This may cause issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1660232/1324033)